# Very poor performance of Istanbul in node >= 4.x

Tags: node.js, performance, mocha.js, istanbul

Running Istanbul-instrumented JavaScript code is **~4 times slower in node 4.x** (and 5.x) than on node 0.12.x.

Specifically, I have a Mocha test that takes ~500 ms to complete on non-instrumented code. The same test takes ~5000 ms on instrumented code in node 0.12.x. The same test takes ~20000 ms on instrumented code in node 5.x.

Any reason why the performance is so much worse in more advanced versions of node?

**Note:** In order to isolate the issue I ran the `istanbul instrument` command. It takes ~1 second to instrument. I then ran the Mocha test on the instrumented code *without generating Istanbul reports or checking coverage*.